# Did Odigo employees receive warning of the 9/11 terror attacks?

Tags: 9-11

[Odigo Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odigo_Messenger) was an Israel-based social network service, that ran from 1999-2004.

According to a 2001 article from the Israeli newspaper, Haaretz:

> Odigo, the instant messaging service, says that two of its workers received messages two hours before the Twin Towers attack on September 11 predicting the attack would happen, and the company has been cooperating with Israeli and American law enforcement, including the FBI, in trying to find the original sender of the message predicting the attack.

Comment: The article is dated 26.09.2001 by the way. Wikipedia has a section on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odigo_Messenger which says it was a non-location-specific threat made in Israel. I'm guessing there's lotsa those. Investigation didn't get anywhere apparently.

Comment: According to this: http://www.911myths.com/html/foia_and_911.html Freedom of Information Act request about this have been denied.